# Navigation bar implementation

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery, performance

I made a navigation bar on the left side of my site. It works perfectly, the only problem is I'm new to jQuery and I think I'm repeating too much code. Is this the case? If it is please help me out.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>DopEYEmine</title>

<!--Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!--Fonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><img class="logo" src="img/whitelogo.svg"><img class="logotwo" src="img/whitelonglogo.svg"></li>
            <li><img class="nav_icons" src="img/about.svg"><a class="about_btn" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><img class="nav_icons" src="img/submit.svg"><a class="submit_btn" href="#">SUBMIT</a></li>
            <li><img class="nav_icons" src="img/contact.svg"><a class="contact_btn" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="about">
        <div class="menucontent">
            <div class="aboutclose closer">CLOSE</div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/logo.png">
            </div>
            <p>"Dopamine: the molecule behind all our most sinful behaviors and secret cravings."</p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="submit">
        <div class="menucontent">
            <div class="submitclose closer">CLOSE</div>

            <form action="submitform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" />
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
        <div class="menucontent">
            <div class="contactclose closer">CLOSE</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mainarea">

    </div>

<!--Javascript-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/browser_hack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Side Bar Nav----------------------------------*/

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.logotwo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    left: 110px;
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95px;
    background: #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: solid 3px #444;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar:hover {
    width: 285px;
    background: #000;
    border-right: none;
}

.nav_icons {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#sidebar li {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

#sidebar ul li:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 88px;
    left: 27px;
}

#sidebar ul li:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 148px;
    left: 27px;
}

#sidebar ul li:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 208px;
    left: 27px;
}

.about_btn,
.submit_btn,
.contact_btn {
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    left: 80px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 200px 5px 5px;
}

.gecko .about_btn,
.gecko .submit_btn,
.gecko .contact_btn { 
    top: -35px;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/*Panel------------------------------------*/

.closer {
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: .7em;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.closer:hover {
    font-size: .75em;
}

.menucontent {
    width: 500px;
}

/*About------------------------------------*/

#about {
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 2px #555;
    opacity: .7;
    display: none;
}

#about p {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

#about img {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
}

/*Contact------------------------------------*/

#contact {
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 2px #555;
    opacity: .7;
    display: none;
}

/*Submit------------------------------------*/

#submit {
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 2px #555;
    opacity: .7;
    display: none;
}

/*Main Area--------------------------------*/

#mainarea {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -0-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//SIDEBAR-------------------------------------------------------
    $('#sidebar').hover(function(){
        $(".about_btn, .submit_btn, .contact_btn").delay(100).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".logotwo").delay(100).fadeIn(1000);
    },function(){
        $(".about_btn, .submit_btn, .contact_btn").fadeOut(10);
        $(".logotwo").fadeOut(10);
    });


//ABOUT PANEL---------------------------------------------------
    var fadeInAbout = function() {
        $('#about').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    };  
    $(".about_btn").click(function () {
        if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
            $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
            fadeInAbout();
        } else if($('#contact').css("display") == "block") {
            $('#contact').fadeOut(10);
            fadeInAbout();
        } else {
            fadeInAbout();
        }
    }); 
    $(".aboutclose").click(function () {
        fadeInAbout();
    });


//SUBMIT PANEL---------------------------------------------------
    var fadeInSubmit = function() {
        $('#submit').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    };
    $(".submit_btn").click(function () {
        if($('#about').css("display") == "block") {
            $('#about').fadeOut(10);
            fadeInSubmit();
        } else if($('#contact').css("display") == "block") {
            $('#contact').fadeOut(10);
            fadeInSubmit();
        } else {
            fadeInSubmit();
        }
    });
    $(".submitclose").click(function () {
        fadeInSubmit();
    });


//CONTACT PANEL---------------------------------------------------
    var fadeInContact = function() {
        $('#contact').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    };

    $(".contact_btn").click(function () {
        if($('#about').css("display") == "block") {
            $('#about').fadeOut(10);
            fadeInContact();
        } else if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
            $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
            fadeInContact();
        } else {
            fadeInContact();
        }
    }); 

    $(".contactclose").click(function () {
        fadeInContact();
    });

//---------------------------------------------------------------
});
```

Comment: try and separate code that is similar and see if you can combine it into one function instead of 2+

Comment: @Geo show him, and you have a full-fledged CR-answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions.

**1.  Always cache your jquery objects if you are going to select the same thing more than once.**

For example:

```
if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
```

Here you are querying the DOM twice to find the `#submit` element.  Instead, save it to a variable and use that variable in both places:

```
var $submit = $('#submit');

if($submit.css("display") == "block") {
    $submit.fadeOut(10);
```

In fact, assuming the elements in question are not dynamically created/removed, you can add this variable assignment at the very top of your code (inside your document.ready) and use it throughout your code.  This is only 1 single query instead of multiple with every click.

**2.  For code readability use `.is(":visible")` to check if an element is visible.**

Instead of `$submit.css("display") == "block"`, which I am assuming you are using to check to see if the element is `display: none` (hidden) vs `display: block` (visible), you can use `$submit.is(":visible")`. This is slightly more concise but more importantly better conveys what the code is doing.

**3. If a function is called in all possible execution paths, call it after the `if`**

In the following code (and other similar code), the function (fadeInContact in this case) is called in every possible execution path:

```
if($('#about').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#about').fadeOut(10);
    fadeInContact();
} else if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
    fadeInContact();
} else {
    fadeInContact();
}
```

In this case, the following is functionally equivalent and doesn't require you to put the function into every if/else branch:

```
if($('#about').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#about').fadeOut(10);
} else if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
}

fadeInContact();
```

**4. Replace all `fadeIn` functions with just one.**

You have three different functions which are identical with exception of the `id` of the element.  One example:

```
var fadeInContact = function() {
    $('#contact').animate({width: 'toggle'});
};
```

All 3 of these could be replace by one with a parameter for the `id`:

```
var fadeInElement = function(id) {
    $('#' + id).animate({width: 'toggle'});
};
```

Then it would be called like this:

```
fadeInElement("contact");
```

**5. Use chaining and filters to consolidate code.**

While not 100% equivalent, making the assumption that only one of your elements is visible at a time, you can replace the following:

```
if($('#about').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#about').fadeOut(10);
} else if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
    $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
}
```

with

```
$("#about, #submit").filter(":visible").fadeOut(10);
```

In fact, `fadeOut` will implicitly do a check for visibility and only fade out if the element is visible.  As a result, the `filter` can be excluded making it simply:

```
$("#about, #submit").fadeOut(10);
```

---

With all changes above incorporated, the following:

```
$(".about_btn").click(function () {
    if($('#submit').css("display") == "block") {
        $('#submit').fadeOut(10);
        fadeInAbout();
    } else if($('#contact').css("display") == "block") {
        $('#contact').fadeOut(10);
        fadeInAbout();
    } else {
        fadeInAbout();
    }
});
```

Becomes:

```
$(".about_btn").click(function () {
    $("#contact, #submit").fadeOut(10);

    fadeInElement("about");
});
```